# Why MongoDB keeps deleted file on disk?

Tags: mongodb, bigdata, storage, diskspace

I am having trouble with MongoDB disk usage. I have an application and using single MongoDB instance on my server. Also i am working with big datas(e.g. one record store average 800MB) and i am using to store GridFS for that. After a while i discover fs.chunks collection size is 110GB and removed all data 
with mongo shell except last 1 month.

Now fs.chunks collection seems 32GB on "MongoDB Compass" but ...\MongoDBDatas\data folder is still 110GB and my disk usage hasn't changed.

What can i do for that?

I have tried db.repairDatabase(); and compact command. Also restarted mongo server however nothing has changed.

Here is my mongo.cfg

```js
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: d:\HealthcarePlatform\MongoDBDatas\log\mongod.log
storage:
    dbPath: d:\HealthcarePlatform\MongoDBDatas\data
net:
   port: 28019
   bindIp: 0.0.0.0
security:
   authorization: enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we delete DB but it didn't free space. so use this

```
sudo lsof +L1
```